Bloc to BLoc communication or use diffrent bloc on on single screen in flutter
The Problem is to implement multiple bloc on a single screen using the BLoC pattern version 8.0. You need to create separate BLoCs (FirstBloc and SecondBloc) to manage the state and business logic for both on a single screen. Additionally, you must implement a CombinedBloc that listens to changes from both FirstBloc and SecondBloc and combines their states into a single state object (CombinedState). The screen UI should update dynamically in response to state changes from both BLoCs.

This is how I will do it:

Define your state

Create your states for each BLoC (FirstBloc and SecondBloc) and group these states in CombinedState
class FirstState {
  final String data;
  FirstState({this.data = ''});
}

class SecondState {
  final String data;
  SecondState({this.data = ''});
}

class CombinedState {
  final FirstState firstState;
  final SecondState secondState;
  CombinedState({required this.firstState, required this.secondState});
}


Define your BLoC

Each BLoC manages its specific logic, and CombinedBloc listens for changes in these two BLoC to update its combined state.
class FirstBloc extends Bloc<FirstEvent, FirstState> {
  FirstBloc() : super(FirstState());
}

class SecondBloc extends Bloc<SecondEvent, SecondState> {
  SecondBloc() : super(SecondState());
}

class CombinedBloc extends Bloc<CombinedEvent, CombinedState> {
  final FirstBloc firstBloc;
  final SecondBloc secondBloc;

  CombinedBloc(this.firstBloc, this.secondBloc)
      : super(CombinedState(firstState: firstBloc.state, secondState: secondBloc.state)) {
    firstBloc.stream.listen((_) => add(UpdateCombinedState()));
    secondBloc.stream.listen((_) => add(UpdateCombinedState()));
  }

  @override
  Stream<CombinedState> mapEventToState(CombinedEvent event) async* {
    yield CombinedState(firstState: firstBloc.state, secondState: secondBloc.state);
  }
}


On the UI side

Use MultiBlocProvider and BlocBuilder to build UI based on state changes
class YourScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => FirstBloc()),
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => SecondBloc()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => CombinedBloc(
          BlocProvider.of<FirstBloc>(context),
          BlocProvider.of<SecondBloc>(context))),
      ],
      child: BlocBuilder<CombinedBloc, CombinedState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Data de FirstBloc : ${state.firstState.data}"),
                Text("Data de SecondBloc : ${state.secondState.data}"),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

